# How to Center Table Content in iOS Mail Client

Tags: html, css, email, razor, html-email

I have a Razor component that I am using to render an email.
The email looks good on most clients I've tested, but on the iOS Mail client, the content is not centered as it should be. The entire content is placed in a table, and I have tried various approaches such as setting `align="center"`, `margin-right="auto"; margin-left="auto"`, but none of them seem to work.

What's interesting is that when I initially open the email, it looks like the first image.

However, if I rotate the phone to landscape mode and then back to portrait mode, the email then looks like the second image, which is exactly how I want it to look.

Most of the ads or promotional emails I receive don't have this problem. Is there anything I can do to fix this? What might be the issue?

[image: first]

[image: second]

Comment: What is the code produced for this?